# Whether is LSH seldom used in flann of OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, matching, nearest-neighbor

We know that the LSH can only use the CV_8U (binary descriptors) and other methods (such as KMeansIndexParams, KDTreeIndexParams and LinearIndexParams) use the CV_32F.

```
void lsh_search(const Mat& data,const Mat& point, Mat& indices, Mat& dists, const int k){

    start_time1 = clock();
    flann::Index flannIndex(data,flann::LshIndexParams(15,2,2),cvflann::FLANN_DIST_HAMMING);   
    finish_time1 = clock();
    flannIndex.save("lshIndex.xml");
    start_time2 = clock();
    flannIndex.knnSearch(point, indices, dists, k,flann::SearchParams(-1));
    finish_time2 = clock();
}
```

I use the code to get nearest 1000 features of one given feature (total 50000 features) and compare the result with that of bruteforce. I find that the result of LSH is the worst when comparing with kdTree or kmeans.

So whether OpenCV seldom uses LSH when it choose the best method by "flann::AutotunedIndexParams"? The best result i get is 25% by changing the parameters of flann::LshIndexParams.

Comment: The parameter of LSH index in your code is quite unusual. What is the parameter you use when getting the best result? Also, how do y ou define a "good" result? By time or by accuracy?

Comment: When I use flann::LshIndexParams(3,8,2) and i get the best result , 252 features are the same with that of BruteForce. And i think a "good" result should be fast and accurate but it firstly should have good accuracy. Multi-Probe LSH is ANN, i think it at least has 80% accuracy so that i can use it and pursue time efficient.

Comment: And each feature has 64 dimensions which represent one 8 * 8 patch.